# How do I add a button at every x degrees?

Tags: ios, swift, degrees, radians

I have a photo in the center and I want to add the array of buttons to the view at certain degrees. I want the first button to be at 2pi, and every button to be 2pi/number of objects in the array away from the first button. In the end the buttons will create a circular path. Below is what I have so far. I can get the starting point, but I am stuck on how to add 2pi/number of objects radians to each button. The center of the circle is in the center of the view.

```
extension Int {
var degreesToRadians : CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var currentuserpic: UIButton!

var userbutton = [UIButton]()
var upimage = [UIImage]()

  func locationsSet(){
    for users in upimage{
        let userbutton = UIButton()
        let degree = CGFloat(360/self.upimage.count)
        userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
        userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
        userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
        userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)

        let buttonWidth = userbutton.frame.width
        let buttonHeight = userbutton.frame.height

        // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
        let viewWidth = self.view.bounds.width
        let viewHeight = self.view.bounds.height


        let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
        let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight


        let pointx = (self.view.bounds.width/2.0) + (currentuserpic.frame.size.width/2.0) + 50
        let pointy = self.view.bounds.height/2.0


        userbutton.center.x = pointx

        userbutton.center.y = pointy

        print(pointx)
        print(pointy)

        self.userbutton.append(userbutton)
        print("called")
        self.view.addSubview(userbutton)


    }
}
```